# single enemy target in a big fight

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a tower defence and I'm having a hard time with my ally and enemy targeting.

The goal is to have five enemies and five allies all at once on the battlefield but each ally is targeting one enemy without crossfighting and stacking on one another (essentially making a 1v1 and even if one of the characters died the winner will not attack another target and will wait untill another target is free to fight).

for example the combat will be the same as Kingdom Rush the moblie game.

This is my attempt and it didnt work well, the targets are constantly change because the combat mode changes to true and they become unvallid to target after that.

```
    void Update()
{

    AttSpd -= Time.deltaTime;
    GameObject[] allAllys = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(Allytag);
    GameObject TargetAlly = null;
    foreach (GameObject Ally in allAllys)

    {
        float distanceToAlly = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Ally.transform.position);
        //looking for target in range
        if (distanceToAlly <= range)
        {
            TargetAlly = Ally;
            if (TargetAlly.GetComponent<AllyUnit>().AllyCombatMode == false  ) {
                Ally.GetComponent<AllyUnit>().AllyCombatMode = true;

                if (distanceToAlly <= CombatRange)
                {
                    //changeing the target to null so the enemy will stop his movement
                    Target = null;
                    if (AttSpd <= 0f)
                    {
                        Damage(TargetAlly.transform);
                        AttRate = 1f / AttCD;
                        AttSpd = AttCD;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    if (TargetAlly != null)
    {
        //walk to fight the target if in range and on target
        if (Target != null)
            TravelToTarget();
        Target = TargetAlly.transform;
        AllyUnit StopHim = TargetAlly.GetComponent<AllyUnit>();
    }
    else
    {
        // going back to patrol
        Target = waypoint.points[wavePointIndex];
        keepGoing();
    }
}


//my combatmod from the enemy viwe
public bool EnemyinCombat()
{
    if (TargetAlly != null)
    {
        EnemyCombatMode = true;
    }
    else
    {
        EnemyCombatMode = false;
    }
    return EnemyCombatMode;
}
```

Comment: what is this monoBehaviour update for? is it game or player? is it backend or client?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure on your algorithm, but I believe you may want to pick a new ally to target only if `TargetAlly` is `null`.  That way your unit will not pick a new target until the first one has been dealt with.  I have a battle simulator with similar code, and once a unit picks a target to attack, he keeps that target, moves within range, and continues to do damage to it until he kills it, at which point the target destroys itself, `TargetAlly` becomes `null` and the unit can pick someone new to target.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should combine the enemy and ally in pair?
Then, when the fight will get over, you just go to target or new ally.